# R: A "tidy" version of a function is much slower than the original, and I'm wondering why

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tidyr

I have data from subjects with unique IDs that come in on multiple visits, each on a separate row of a data frame. Some information, like sex or birth year, may only be collected at one visit, but is relevant at any of the visits. For the visits where the information was not collected, that field will be an NA. So, I created a function that will copy a subject's information for a given field to all visits, replacing the NAs. It worked, but the code is clunky, and now that I'm learning tidy data wrangling, I wanted to incorporate that to make the code cleaner. I also expected it to speed up the process, but that's not what happened.

First, here's some toy data:

```
data <- tibble(record_id = c(rep(LETTERS[1:4], 3)), 
               year1 = c(NA, NA, 2000, 2001, 2002, rep(NA, 7)),
               year2 = c(rep(NA, 5), 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, rep(NA, 3)))
```

The following will give the desired outcome:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(year1, .by_group = T) %>% 
  fill(year1) %>%
  arrange(year2) %>%
  fill(year2)
```

Before I got tidy, I created this code, and it worked just fine.

```
mash.old <- function(data, variable){
  x <- data[!is.na(data[,variable]),] %>%
    distinct(record_id, .keep_all = T)
  x <- as.data.frame(x)
  for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
    if(is.na(data[i,variable]) &
       data[i, "record_id"] %in% x$record_id){
      id <- data[i, "record_id"]
      data[i,variable] <- x[x$record_id == as.character(id),
                            variable]
    }else{
      next
    }
  }
  rm(x, id, i)
  return(data)
}
```

I could run

```
data <- mash.old(data, 'year1')
data <- mash.old(data, 'year2')
```

and get the desired outcome.

I wanted to improve it by allowing it to accept a vector of variables to perform the function on, have the option of choosing the grouping variable (subject id variable name), and to use dplyr/tidyr. So I created this:

```
mash.new <- function(data, variables, grouping.var = record_id){
  for(i in variables){
    data <- data %>%
      group_by(!!enquo(grouping.var)) %>%
      arrange((!!sym(i)), .by_group = T) %>%
      fill(!!sym(i)) %>%
      ungroup()
  }
  return(data)
}
```

Now `mash.new(data, c('year1, 'year2'))` will return the expected results. No problem for this small data frame.

My actual data frame has 15762 rows, and I wanted to run the function for twelve variables. `mash.old()` took about four minutes to do this. `mash.new()` said that it would take about three hours, so I stopped it after about five minutes or so.

My question is why the huge difference? I looked at my first function as being amateurish and clunky, I thought I was making an improvement. Is it just that the process of grouping, arranging, filling and grouping requires a lot more computing power? Is there a better way to write this? I'm self taught and just trying to improve my skills.

### Edit

Thanks for the help. Here is the function I ended up using. Even though Cole's `data.table` version is faster, I opted to stick with the `dplyr` method, just because that is what I know.

```
mash <- function(data, variables, grouping.var = record_id){
   data <- data %>%
      arrange(!!enquo(grouping.var)) %>%
      group_by(!!enquo(grouping.var)) %>%
      mutate_at(vars(!!!variables), 
                function(x) zoo::na.locf(x[order(x)], na.rm = F)) %>%
      ungroup()
   return(data)
}
#Note that if there are two different entries for a given subject in a 
#variable, this will fill with the data that comes last in the sort order
```

Comment: `data %>% group_by(record_id) %>% fill(-record_id) %>% fill(-record_id, .direction = 'up')`?

Comment: `fill` is generally pretty slow. I'd replace it with `zoo::na.locf` and see what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest improvement would be to `group_by()` once. Right now, you are doing 12 groupings and ungroupings which adds a lot of unnecessary overhead. Plus the new function re-assigns everything back to itself - if we're on `year1` there's no reason to mess with the memory of `year2` or `report_id`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

data%>%
  arrange(record_id)%>%
  group_by(record_id)%>%
  mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), function(x) zoo::na.locf(x[order(x)], na.rm = F))%>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 12 x 3
   record_id year1 year2
   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A          2002  2006
 2 A          2002  2006
 3 A          2002  2006
 4 B            NA  2003
 5 B            NA  2003
 6 B            NA  2003
 7 C          2000  2004
 8 C          2000  2004
 9 C          2000  2004
10 D          2001  2005
11 D          2001  2005
12 D          2001  2005
```

Also, my ultimate favorite would be `data.table`. It's short and sweet:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

dt <- as.data.table(data)

vars_n <- names(dt)[-1] #included if you want to make a function later
dt[,lapply(.SD, function(x) zoo::na.locf(x[order(x)], na.rm = F)), keyby = record_id, .SDcols = vars_n]
```

It's also the fastest

```
Unit: milliseconds
           expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
     cole_dplyr  3.2388  3.39800  3.588391  3.47175  3.62610   6.6420   100
       cole_dt2  1.6135  1.83535  2.082963  1.96230  2.07435   6.7179   100
    mashing_old  4.6119  4.86305  5.175244  4.94930  5.10220   9.1026   100
    mashing_new 16.1860 16.82445 18.610696 17.30585 18.01270 101.6192   100
 OP_non_mashing 15.1633 15.57970 16.914889 16.10400 16.97860  46.5837   100
```

And all of my code - the benchmarks are at the bottom:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(record_id = c(rep(LETTERS[1:4], 3)), 
               year1 = c(NA, NA, 2000, 2001, 2002, rep(NA, 7)),
               year2 = c(rep(NA, 5), 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, rep(NA, 3)))

data <- tibble(record_id = c(rep(LETTERS[1:4], 3)), 
               year1 = c(NA, NA, 2000, 2001, 2002, rep(NA, 7)),
               year2 = c(rep(NA, 5), 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2002, rep(NA, 2)))

data

library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(data)

vars_n <- names(dt)[-1] #included if you want to make a function later
dt[,lapply(.SD, function(x) zoo::na.locf(x[order(x)], na.rm = F)), keyby = record_id, .SDcols = vars_n]


data%>%
  arrange(record_id)%>%
  group_by(record_id)%>%
  mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), function(x) zoo::na.locf(x[order(x)], na.rm = F))%>%
  ungroup()

mash.old <- function(data, variable){
  x <- data[!is.na(data[,variable]),] %>%
    distinct(record_id, .keep_all = T)
  x <- as.data.frame(x)
  for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
    if(is.na(data[i,variable]) &
       data[i, "record_id"] %in% x$record_id){
      id <- data[i, "record_id"]
      data[i,variable] <- x[x$record_id == as.character(id),
                            variable]
    }else{
      next
    }
  }
  rm(x, id, i)
  return(data)
}

mash.new <- function(data, variables, grouping.var = record_id){
  for(i in variables){
    data <- data %>%
      group_by(!!enquo(grouping.var)) %>%
      arrange((!!sym(i)), .by_group = T) %>%
      fill(!!sym(i)) %>%
      ungroup()
  }
  return(data)
}

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  cole_dplyr = {
    data %>%
      arrange(record_id)%>%
      group_by(record_id)%>%
      mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), function(x) zoo::na.locf(x[order(x)], na.rm = F))%>%
      ungroup()
  }
  ,
  # cole_dt = {
  #   dt1 <- copy(dt)
  #   
  #   vars_n <- names(dt1)[-1]
  #   dt1[, (vars_n) := lapply(.SD, function(x) zoo::na.locf(sort(x))), keyby = record_id]
  # },
  cole_dt2 = {
    dt[,lapply(.SD, function(x) zoo::na.locf(x[order(x)], na.rm = F)), keyby = record_id]
    },
  mashing_old = {
    data1 <- data
    data1 <- mash.old(data1, 'year1')
    data1 <- mash.old(data1, 'year2')
  }
  ,
  mashing_new = {
    mash.new(data, c('year1', 'year2'))
  }
  , OP_non_mashing = {
    data %>%
      group_by(record_id) %>%
      arrange(year1, .by_group = T) %>%
      fill(year1) %>%
      arrange(year2) %>%
      fill(year2)
  }
)
```

Comment: Nice answer. I would suggest moving the `as.data.table()` out of the 'measured in  the benchmark' function and maybe making it a simple `copy()` (as the data gets mutated). If I do that the gap wides further in favor of `data.table`.